# Remotely operated widget - styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, widget

I am currently learning web development (mostly with rails). Thing is, I want to create a widget that displays a website in an iframe. Each user should be able to customize the widget -- like change size of the widget, orientation, etc. The user should be able to embed the widget into their webpage as well (kinda like Wordpress)

If I generate some embed code and let that code obtain a javascript file, I can add widgets with dynamic HTML and CSS. The problem is, though, each user can customize the widget -- so I need to make the JS file correspondingly alter itself to each user's preferences.

Any idea how to proceed? Thanks.
Part of the JS file (all style properties are allowed to be changed by the user):

```
doc = window.document;
widgetsBtn = doc.createElement('div');
widgetsBtn.id = "widgetsBtn";
widgetsBtn.style.position = 'fixed';
widgetsBtn.style.right = 0;
widgetsBtn.style.bottom = 0;
widgetsBtn.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; 
widgetsBtn.style.float = 'bottom'; 
widgetsBtn.style.width = '100px';
widgetsBtn.style.height = '50px';
widgetsBtn.style.textAlign = 'center';
widgetsBtn.style.paddingTop = '10px';
 ...
doc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(widgetsBtn);
widgetsBtn.innerHTML = "View webpage";
```